# Adding stuff to listview from textbox

Tags: vb.net

id like to know how to take one of my text boxs or strings and put it in a listview.. well not really let me show u wants going on.

i have a 2 text box with the following stuff

TextBox1

```
 cat123
 hatcat
 quanwall
 samiam12
```

TextBox2

```
 John
 will
 sam
 dan
```

i want to take TextBox1's text and put it in one of the columns in the ListView. for example. ListView has 2 columns saying usernames and realnames, and TextBox1 is the usernames and TextBox2 is the realnames. So i want to take each line in TextBox1 to match up with the RealNames(TextBox2) all in ListView.

iv bin using the

```
        Dim Q As New ListViewItem
        Q.Text = Host
        Q.SubItems.Add(User)
        Q.SubItems.Add(Pass)
        ListView1.Items.Add(Q)
```

to add the strings to the listview

I need this information ASAP, Thx u <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (To listview1 put your listview name)

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each l In TextBox1.Lines
        ListView1.Items.Add(l)
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TextBox2.Lines(i))
        i += 1
    Next
    i = 0
```

Comment: thx man But i need to know how to add another subitem the same way, so its added to the next column.

Comment: From another textbox to a thrird column?

Comment: nvm i figured it out @BanForFun

Answer (score 0):

While the straightforward answer to your question is rather simple, your posted question raises issues. You are using Listbox and Listview interchangeably, yet they are two different controls. Moreover you seem to suggest your Textbox holds multiple values where the intention of a Textbox is to hold one distinct value or string of text.

As these controls are Windows Forms controls, your use of "Dim Q As New ListviewItem" may not be neccessary.

I would suggest reading up more on the controls you want to use, how they are used and in what context.

The simple straightforward answer to your question could be:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text)
```

For reference: [How to: Add and Remove Items with the Windows Forms ListView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fds7919(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Im sorry that u still do not under stand what i wanted to say, and no "YOUR STRAIGHT FOWERED Answer" did not help me. im also very sorry i wrote listbox ones in the begin of the text. Im Also VERy sorry that u dont understand that i didnt try to say that the text boxs have more values but to tell u that its on different lines. i wanted to take both of the text boxs and take the LINES of text and put them in different Columns IN  the **LISTVIEW**. so there would have to be a code that separates the lines of text and adds the line of text as a row for the List view.

Comment: @Zeltronplayz : If you want to separate text, use [**String.Split()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your user names are stored in TextBox1 and your real names are stored in TextBox2

```
Public Sub AddListViewItemsFromTextboxes()

        Dim Host As String = "SomeHost" 'you mentioned a host in the code snippet in your question, not sure where this comes from

        Dim TextBox1String As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim TextBox2String As String = TextBox2.Text

        Dim TextBox1Lines() As String = TextBox1String.Split(vbNewLine)
        Dim TextBox2Lines() As String = TextBox2String.Split(vbNewLine)

        If(TextBox1Lines.Count <> TextBox2Lines.Count)
            'possible error handling here
            MsgBox("Each user must have both a real name and a username.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For NameIndex As Integer = 0 to (TextBox1Lines.Count - 1)
            Dim UserName As String = TextBox1Lines(NameIndex)
            Dim RealName As String = TextBox2Lines(NameIndex)

            Dim Item As New ListViewItem
            Item.Text = Host

            Dim UserNameSubItem As New ListViewitem.ListViewSubItem
            UserNameSubItem.Text = UserName

            Item.SubItems.Add(UserNameSubItem)

            Dim RealNameSubItem As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
            RealNameSubItem.Text = RealName

            Item.SubItems.Add(RealNameSubItem)

            ListView1.Items.Add(Item)

        Next        

    End Sub
```

Example GUI:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/du95F.png

EDIT: Added third column

Comment: I'm not really sure if you want to display 2 columns of data or 3 columns in your listview, if you want 2 columns look at the previous version of my answer